# SQL security to database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, security, database-connection

I am using Visual Basic.net and have a question regarding a SQL connection to an online database.

If I connect to a SQL database via code, how secure is this connection? If I have the password and address of the server in code, can a user work out the login and tamper with the database?

Comment: Are you using mixed mode or integrated auth? Is it a web application or a desktop app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a program a while back that connected to a SQL database which I distributed, before I knew how easily .Net can be decompiled. It is extremely easy to get pretty much your full source code which would allow anyone to view the connection information. Even if you encrypt the connection strings, if the encryption/decryption is written as a sub in your program, you are providing them the tools to decrypt it anyways (which will just take up more of their time and cause them to be more malicious).

The way I got around this was to completely lock down the permissions of the user so that they can only see/select/update the areas I wanted them too. I restricted all actions they did not need and only allowed my application to use stored procedures. Even with that in place, users could still cause some problems with those.

There are tools out there called obfuscators that will scramble the source code to make it harder to read. Note that I said harder, and not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

"If I have the password and address of the server in code, can a user work out the login and tamper with the database?"

Yes - using freely available tools on the internet a user could decompile your code and find the password and username.

If you need to store a password, store it as an encrypted  string and then decrypt it just before connecting to the database.